# ¿Existe un software en el que se pueda cargar 29 GigaBytes?

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo una base que pesa 29 GygaBytes y quiero saber si existe un Sofware como ACL, SQL, en el que se pueda cargar una base de ese tamaño, el archivo lo tengo en DBF o alguna manera de partir la base

Comment: se puede, por terminal

Answer (score 4):

En realidad 29 GB no es nada para cualquier manejador de Bases de datos moderno. Las limitaciones podrían venir más fácilmente del sistema operativo o del servidor donde estarán alojadas las tablas. La Doc de MySQL dice que **una tabla MyISAM puede tener un tamaño de hasta 256TB**... y hasta más, si se lo indicas en el `CREATE TABLE`, así que 29GB... eso no es nada.

Por ejemplo, MySQL [dice lo siguiente en su Documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html):

**C.10.3 Límites en el tamaño de la tabla**

El tamaño de tabla máximo efectivo para las bases de datos MySQL **suele estar determinado por las restricciones del sistema operativo sobre el tamaño de los archivos, no por los límites internos de MySQL**. Para obtener información actualizada sobre los límites del tamaño del archivo del sistema operativo, consulte la documentación específica de su sistema operativo.

Usuarios de Windows, tengan en cuenta que FAT y VFAT (FAT32) no se consideran adecuados para su uso en producción con MySQL. Utilice NTFS en su lugar.

Si encuentra un error de tabla completa, hay varias razones por las que pudo haber ocurrido:

- Es posible que el disco esté lleno.
- Está utilizando tablas InnoDB y se ha quedado sin espacio en un archivo de espacio de tablas InnoDB. El tamaño máximo del espacio de tabla es también el tamaño máximo de una tabla. Para conocer los límites de tamaño del espacio de tablas, consulte la [Sección 15.8.8, "Límites de las tablas InnoDB"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html).
- Generalmente, **se recomienda el particionamiento de tablas en varios archivos de tablas para tablas de tamaño superior a 1 TB**.
- Has alcanzado un límite de tamaño de archivo del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, está utilizando tablas MyISAM en un sistema operativo que admite archivos de hasta 2 GB de tamaño y ha alcanzado este límite para el archivo de datos o el archivo de índice.
- Está utilizando una tabla MyISAM y el espacio requerido para la tabla excede lo permitido por el tamaño del puntero interno. **MyISAM permite que los archivos de datos e índice crezcan hasta 256TB de forma predeterminada, pero este límite se puede cambiar hasta el tamaño máximo permitido de 65.536TB (2567 - 1 bytes)**.
- Si necesita una tabla MyISAM que sea mayor que el límite predeterminado y su sistema operativo admita archivos grandes, la instrucción CREATE TABLE soporta las opciones `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` y `MAX_ROWS`. [Consulte la Sección 14.1.18, "Sintaxis de `CREATE TABLE`"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). El servidor utiliza estas opciones para determinar el tamaño que debe permitir en una tabla.

---

#### Migrar de dbf a MySql

Este tutorial podría serte de ayuda: [Importar archivos DBF a MySQL](http://manelperez.com/linux/importar-archivos-dbf-a-mysql/)